# Unable to resolve host name in WSL

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

In almost any action I do in Windows Subsystem for Linux, I get a notification "How to resolve host name". Why would this happen in each fresh install and how to solve it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know why it happens (please improve the answer with an explanation), here is a working solution for this problem:

### 1. Execute:

```
nano /etc/hostname
```

Type your machine name in capital letters ( it would be something like DESKTOP-SOMETHING). Delete anything besides your machine name.

Save and exit.

### 2. Then, execute:

```
nano /etc/hosts
```

Then, Make sure the file's first two rows looks as follows:

```
  127.0.0.1 localhost.localdomain localhost
  127.0.1.1 DESKTOP-SOMETHING
```

Save and exit.

Comment: If the /etc/hosts file is removed (or just move it to a temporary location), WSL automatically recreates a new hosts file with the correct host name.

Comment: I already have all of these entries and I still can't resolve some domain on WSL that my Windows can resolve.

Answer (score 14):

1. check if there exists a resolv.conf symbolic link and file:

```
cd /etc
ls -lha
stat resolv.conf
```

you should see a symbolic link pointing to:

```
  File: resolv.conf -> ../run/resolvconf/resolv.conf
  Size: 29              Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   symbolic link
```

The original file in ../run/resolvconf/resolv.conf will be newly created booting into WSL Ubuntu and has the following content:

```
# This file was automatically generated by WSL. To stop automatic generation of this file, add the following entry to /etc/wsl.conf:>
# [network]
# generateResolvConf = false
nameserver 172.23.0.1
```

the nameserver address might differ in your case

2. create a wsl.conf file in the root etc folder (you may need sudo):

`sudo nano /etc/wsl.conf`

3. paste the following lines in the file and exit saving it (Ctrl+X):

```
[network]
generateResolvConf = false
```

4. delete the symbolic link to the resolv.conf file

```
cd /etc
sudo rm resolv.conf
```

5. create a new resolv.conf file in /etc

```
sudo nano resolv.conf
```

and paste the following content into it saving it with (Ctrl+O and Ctrl+X):

```
# This file was automatically generated by WSL. To stop automatic generation of this file, 
# add the following entry to /etc/wsl.conf:>
# [network]
# generateResolvConf = false
# nameserver 172.23.0.1
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

Comment: This should be marked as the answer

Answer (score 2):

In my case, helpful command was:

```bash
echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8" | sudo tee /etc/resolv.conf > /dev/null
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Delete the existing /etc/hosts file
2. Restart WSL
3. Create new /etc/hosts file with required entries

Comment: Thank you, this worked for me. Any idea why this happens?

Comment: This is an autogenerated file during installation. It shouldn't fail unless subsequently either the machine name or domain changes or in case of error in file due to manual mappings entered.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me in order to resolve local windows network hosts within WSL2 was to add the following internal DNS resolution entries (nameservers) in `/etc/resolv.config`:

```
search <name-of-my-internal-ad-domain.net>
nameserver 10.0.xx.xxx  # local WAN DNS server
nameserver 10.0.xx.xxx  # local WAN DNS server
nameserver 1.1.1.1

sudo tee /etc/resolv.conf << EOF
search <name-of-my-internal-ad-domain.net>
nameserver 10.0.xx.xxx
nameserver 10.0.xx.xxx
nameserver 1.1.1.1
```

Answer (score 0):

None of the above answers worked for me. What did work was **disabling IPv6** on the network connection e.g.

1. Go to Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network Connections
2. Right click on whichever network connection you are using, choose Properties
3. Deselect "Internet Protocol Version 6 (TCP/IPv6)
4. Click OK

No need to reboot or anything, it worked immediately. Hope that can help someone else.